# Extracting text from *.txt files in R

Tags: r, regex, text, tm

I've used Expressions for Mac to confirm my Regex works but I can't find a command to extract information from my text file. I have 2,500 text files and I need to pull out the date of each document in order to populate a dataset. FYI, "date" is the first variable to extract, there will be others. The format of the files varies and there are multiple dates. I'm only interested in the first date of each document. Some documents have a new line with the date, others start the line with the word "Date" or "Dated".

Example of each text document:

```
Bangor
dorset
LL56 43r

date:         10 july 2009
take notice:  the blah blah blah text goes here and there's lots of it.
action:
```

Regex that works:

```
"\\d{1,2}\\s+(?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s+\\d{4}"
```

The text document is visible in R Studio environment as a single element character vector. I'd like to extract the text "as is" so something like...

```
> strapply(NoFN, ("\\d{1,2}\\.?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december\\.\\d{4}")[[1]]
> [1] 10 july 2009
```

Obviously that doesn't actually work!

Many thanks!
Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is not right for R because you need to escape the `\` character.

The regular expression should be:

```
"\\d{1,2}\\s+(?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s+\\d{4}"
```

If you use the `stringr` package, and your text is loaded to `txt` you can do:

```
library(stringr)

txt = "Bangor dorset LL56 43r\n date: 10 july 2009 \n take notice: the blah blah blah text goes here and there's lots of it. action:"

str_match(string = txt, pattern = "\\d{1,2}\\s+(?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s+\\d{4}")

        [,1]          
[1,] "10 july 2009"
```

Comment: Thanks, I typed in the \\ but when the question loaded here there was only a single \.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does it. It uses the built-in variable `month.name` and unlike in the question, groups the months with `()`.

```
txt <- "\n date: 10 july 2009 \n take notice: the blah blah blah text goes here and there's lots of it. action:"

pattern <- paste(tolower(month.name), collapse = "|")
pattern <- paste0("(", pattern, ")")
pattern <- paste("[[:digit:]]{1,2}[[:space:]]*", pattern, "[[:digit:]]{4}")

m <- regexpr(pattern, txt)
regmatches(txt, m)
#[1] "10 july 2009"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, this works a treat!

library(stringr)

txt = "Bangor dorset LL56 43r\n date: 10 july 2009 \n take notice: the blah blah blah text goes here and there's lots of it. action:"

str_match(string = txt, pattern = "\d{1,2}\s+(?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s+\d{4}")

```
    [,1]
```

[1,] "10 july 2009"